# Combine Bootstrap3 media object and carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to combine bootstrap3 `media-object` and `carousel`, to be more precise I want to put `media-object` inside `carousel` and cycle it.

You can see [media-object](https://jsfiddle.net/copser/z8h5xe87/1/) here and I have tried to combine it with `carousel` [here](https://jsfiddle.net/copser/qozcbcu4/6/). But as you can see image is to big and media-body have `text-center`, I want to preserve layout of `media-object` inside `carousel`.

Can some one help me build this, because the only way I understand this is that I put `media-body` inside `carousel-caption` and `img` inside `item-active` and with `css` I manipulate `media` inside `carousel`.
Is there a way that I just cycle `media-object`. Here is the picture of the thing I want to achieve.
[image]

Comment: You should probably investigate the source code of the element and try to reproduce the results on your own, unless you struggle to understand the code.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand how to mix it, I was trying to do it multiple times, I want to understand, is there a way to code `media-object` to be `carousel` using bootstrap?

Comment: Why do that? Why not put the `.media-object` inside `.item` of the carousel?

Comment: And this picture is psd, need to code it

Comment: But I did put it, in the jsfiddle example, but it does not look like `media-object`, does it?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that link, a `jsfiddle here: xxx` might be more eye catching.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mxsbdz06/ Straight from Bootstrap docs.

Comment: Interesting, I can work on this example, thanks